# $\frac{d\textbf{y}}{dt} = \textbf{f(y)}$ representation of ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE's :

$$\frac{ds}{dt} = 1-s-\frac{msx}{a+s}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{msx}{a+s} - x$$

I need to represent the system in the form $\frac{d\textbf{y}}{dt} = \textbf{f(y)}$.

I get that they're asking me some kind of vectorial representation where we have $\textbf{f}(t,\textbf{y})$  and:

$$\textbf{y}(t) = \begin{pmatrix} y_1(t) \\y_2(t)  \end{pmatrix}$$

but I'm confused about how to get there since both the function $x$ and $s$ appear in both equations. Factorizing the function $x$ in the second equation is no problem but in the first equation the function $s$ appears as well in the denominator so factorizing is no option. I'm still confused about the representation they're asking me to do so maybe I'm in the wrong path factorizing the functions. I would apreciate some help. Thanks in andvance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $y=(s,x)^T$ and $f(y)=(f_1(y),f_2(y))^T$ with
$$
f_1(y)=1-s-\frac{msx}{a+x},\quad f_2(y)=\frac{msx}{a+x}-x
$$

If you want $y=(y_1,y_2)$, replace $s$ and $x$ above with $y_1$ and $y_2$ repectively.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was very confused but it was simpler than I thought. Thanks!

Comment: @JeniferÁvila you are welcome!